# packet sending in low speed in linux

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel

recently working on a project which is to forward packets in a high rate (more than 500Mbitps). I have tried 2 methods, but they don't work.
The host is a vm, ubuntu-11.10 32bit, the nic is r8169, 1000Mb.

1. I used raw sock with a buff whose size depends on the the size of the packets received(no more than 1500). I put sendto function in loop(while(1)), make sure it can send as fast as I can. but the send speed is much more less than the speed r8169 can do, it is about 100-200Mbitps. Can I suppose that socket can not do high rate sending? but why such as Iperf as well as uses socket can perform better? or Is there anything I can do to make sending faster?
2. I used dev_queue_xmit() in kernel. I put the function in a loop(while(1)) in a kthread with schedule(). but the sending speed turned out no more than 300Mbitps. I know call dev_queue_xmit maybe is not a good idea, but I still don't understand why the speed is that low?

please, need help..

or anyone could provide me a classic solution to forwarding packets in a high rate?
my socket is simple:

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP)/*IPPROTO_RAW*/);
struct ifreq if_idx;
char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];
struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
char buf[1400];
struct packet_mreq mr;
struct ether_header *eh;
int ret = 0;
struct ifreq if_mac;

strcpy(ifName, "eth1");//used for sending
memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0)
    perror("SIOCGIFINDEX\n");
memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0)
    perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR\n");

socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
/* Address length*/
socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
/* Destination MAC */
socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(0xA000);
socket_address.sll_addr[0] = 0x00;
socket_address.sll_addr[1] = 0x24;
socket_address.sll_addr[2] = 0xe8;
socket_address.sll_addr[3] = 0x82;
socket_address.sll_addr[4] = 0xec;
socket_address.sll_addr[5] = 0x82;
printf("%d\n",bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address))); 

memset (&mr, 0, sizeof(mr));
mr.mr_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
//mr.mr_type = PACKET_MR_PROMISC;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mr,sizeof(mr));

eh = (struct ether_header *)buf;
eh->ether_shost[0] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0];
eh->ether_shost[1] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1];
eh->ether_shost[2] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2];
eh->ether_shost[3] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3];
eh->ether_shost[4] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4];
eh->ether_shost[5] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5];
eh->ether_dhost[0] = 0x00;
eh->ether_dhost[1] = 0x24;
eh->ether_dhost[2] = 0xe8;
eh->ether_dhost[3] = 0x82;
eh->ether_dhost[4] = 0xec;
eh->ether_dhost[5] = 0x82;
eh->ether_type = htons(0xA000);
while(1)
    ret = write(sockfd,buf,1000);
printf("%d\n",ret);
return 0;
```

Comment: How did you measure the speed?

Comment: I use wireshark in the other end and check the summary after a while.

Comment: Don't use wireshark on the other end. That doesn't show your sending rate in isolation -- that value will be impacted by all sorts of other factors (network bandwidth, receiving NIC speed, etc.). Measure on the sending side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [writev()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) which allows you to provide multiple buffers? Are you sourcing the data from a file? If so, you may want to investigate sendfile().